# My Site is under DDoS Attack

Tags: ddos

I hosted my website couponx.com in google cloud. For 24 hrs my site is under DDOS Attack. I have tried every way to get my site back. I spoke with Cloudflare as well. Still, the issue is not resolved. Can anyone suggest me how to stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends, you can check which IP addresses are trying to connect to your site, and manualy block them, try to block also IP range.

Also you can do "under attack mode" if you use cloudflare.

Possibility is also that, you can block countries from where is attack going, but thats really harsh solution and may inpact your traffic.

Comment: Thanks, we did it. Blocked IP addresses.

Answer (score -1):

The only way to combat a DDoS attack is to have a big enough pipe to absorb it. If you are indeed hosting everything with Google, they should be able to provide you with the required tools.

Take a look here: https://cloud.google.com/armor/